# Image in div is cut off between page when print

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsreport

how to make the image go to the next page when it doesn't fit in a page. Is there any way to do it ? I'm using jsreport to create a template. Currently, my div already go to next page, if it doesn't not fit in one page. so the image will follow the div, but if the image is many, doesn't fit in one page, it will be cut off.

```js
string+="<tr><td colspan='100%' style='font-size: 10px !important;width: fit-content !important;'>";
        data[index]["Updates"].forEach(function(value2,index2){
            string+="<div class='border mb-1 pt-1 px-2 divSection'><div class= 'row mb-1'>" +
            "<div class='col'>("+value2["Category"]+") \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0"+value2["Datetime"]+"\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 "+value2["Commented By"]+"</div>"+
            "</div>" +
            "<div class= 'row mb-1'>" +
            "<div class='col'>"+value2["Asset"]+"</div>"+
            "</div>" +
            "<div class= 'row mb-2'>" +
            "<div class='col'>"+value2["Comment"]+"</div>"+
            "</div>" +
            "<div class= 'row mb-1'>" ;
            for (var i = 0; i < value2["Attch."].length; i++){
                string+="<div class='col-3  d-flex justify-content-between pt-1 picSection'><img class='picSection' src='"+value2["Attch."][i]+"' min-height='35%' width='100%'></div>";
            }
            string+="</div></div>";
            // string+=""+value2["Datetime"]+"";
        })

    string+="</td></tr>";
    })
```

```css
 @media print  
            {
                .divSection{
                    page-break-inside: avoid;
                }
                .picSection{
                    page-break-inside: avoid;
                    overflow: hidden !important;
                }
            }
            @media print{@page 
                {
                    size: landscape;
                }
            }

            img {
                max-width:230px;
                max-height:230px;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
            }
```

[image: This is an example image that being cut off]